# How to draw rounded rectangle with borders only on top?

Tags: flutter, dart

There are multiple ways to draw a rounded rectangle. I want to draw a rounded rectangle with content inside. However, only the top of the rectangle should be rounded.

I tried

```
Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.red))),
        child: Column(
          children: [Text("hello")],
        ));
```

but I get a red line with "hello" on bottom. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With BorderRadius.vertical you can choose top corners or bottom corners.

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
   top: Radius.circular(20),
 ),
),
```

And with BorderRadius.only you can choose any corner.

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
   topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
   topRight: Radius.circular(20),
 ),
),
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little trick

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(15.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(13.0),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(13.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("hello"),
                ],
              ) 
              ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Container(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      color: Colors.yourColor,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: `Cannot provide both a color and a decoration
To provide both, use "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)".
'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 15: 'color == null || decoration == null'`

Comment: @Paprika the solution is described in the error itself, read carefully

Comment: @Paprika remove color from your container and add it to decoration. I have updated my code, see.